# A question of redundancy re Git branch updates and CI/CD flows

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration

We are using gihub to manage our CI/CD pipeline and I noticed that on a PR, every update I run to align the PR with target branch, I trigger the whole unit testing flow, since the head of the branch has changed, I want to explore if this is not a redundant action that can be excluded, if at all.

The testing flow triggers on every push into a published branch, which means that anything that was merged has passed all the tests. This essentially means that any update I run on my branch would include all those PRs that passed the full test flow, so my question is, why would I need to run a full test flow on every update to my branch?

Think about the situation where you have a large team and right before release everyone is putting their PRs in, moreover, after every PR gets merged, my PR would need a new update, which means another test run, github doesn't have "merge after tests complete successfully", so that means that I'm in a race to merge quickly before the next PR merges in, and if I don't > update > test run, would be happy to get your feedback on this.

Thx,
Bud

Comment: Not sure why i'm not getting hits on this question. There is no code here, sorry.

Comment: Yep, no code usually gets less views and answers. Also, many people filter questions by tag to find the most relevant ones for them to answer, and I don't think these topics are too popular. I actually came here from the answer you created a few days ago, as it might just get closed (it's probably better suited for a comment as you are just speculating, given the lack of detail in the question). I just wanted to give you some reputation to help you get the commenting privilege.

Answer (score 0):

That's totally expected: If you have a project with 5 PRs that have passed all tests and one of them gets merged, the other ones need to be re-tested and maybe updated to resolve conflicts, as the merged changes might have caused something in the remaining PRs to break (the code in your PR might be using a function that was updated by the PR that just got merged).

[GitHub `auto-merge`](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/managing-auto-merge-for-pull-requests-in-your-repository) might help managing the PR-merge flow with the team, so that most of the time another PR gets merged before yours you'll only have to click the `Update branch` button (assuming there are no conflicts) and then, once all checks have passed, it will be automatically merged.

However, I would say if that happens too often, you should try to create smaller PRs and merge them more often, to reduce the chances of having merge conflicts and a long queue of PRs on release day.